# How to align items in FlastList with maximum width?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have read a lot of similar questions here but I can't still align items in `FlatList` to the center horizontally. Below is my component:

```
const renderItem = ({item}: ListRenderItemInfo<Post>) => (
  <NewsPost title={item.msg} style={styles.listItem} />
)

const HomeScreen = ({injector}: Props) => {
  // Some code
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.frame}>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.list}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.listContent}
        data={data?.posts}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        onEndReached={loadData}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  frame: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  list: {
    width: '100%',
    overflow: 'visible',
  },
  listContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  listItem: {
    maxWidth: 600,
  },
})
```

And how it looks on device:

[image: Screenshot]

How to align items to the center with a maximum width?

**P.S.** I've tried `marginHorizontal: 'auto'` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the alignItems: "center", you should take a look at flexbox css and then take into account that react-native uses a default
flex-direction: "column", changing the axis.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  frame: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center', // add this to center your content
  },
  list: {
    width: '100%',
    overflow: 'visible',
  },
  listContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  listItem: {
    maxWidth: 600,
  },
})
```